# How to extract a subsequent word after pattern match using perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl, strawberry-perl

Sample line from a file:

```
one two three uname whirlcano four five
```

I want to extract the user names from multiple files

```
foreach $file (@file_names)
{
    open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file)
    or die "Could not open file '$file' $!";

    while (my $row = <$fh>)
    {
        if($row =~  "uname")
        {
            #here I want to extract only the immediate word after "uname", which is "whirlcano" in the above example.
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression capturing group to capture the username:

```
while (my $row = <$fh>) {
    chomp($row); # strip newline character

    # capture first group of word characters after uname and one or more spaces
    my ($username) = $row =~ m/uname\s+(\w+)/;
    ....
}
```

You can change `\s+` in the above example to whatever delimiter your file has, but typically when parsing CSV type files using a *real* CSV parser is better than regular expressions. [`Text::CSV_XS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS) is one such parser that is popular.

For more information about capturing groups in regular expressions, please refer to the Capture Groups section of [`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-groups)

Comment: Hi Hunter, these are log files with no standard delimiters. above regex is returning "uname" and not "whirlcano". This might be basic stuff, but I am not very good at regex. Please help, thanks.

Comment: If the row is actually the row you supplied in your question, then the regular expression I supplied will capture the username